# MySQL: how to keep top 1000 rows for each value of a column

Tags: mysql

I need some help with this query: I want to delete the following rows from my table.
The table has 4 columns: UserID, UserName, Tag, Score.

**I want to keep only the top 1000 users with highest score, for each Tag.**

So I need to order by score, and to keep the first 1000 users for each tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the other answer,

```
DELETE FROM table t1
WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM table t2
                     WHERE t2.tag = t1.tag
                     ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1000);
```

This assumes that `UserID` is a unique/primary key field. If it's not, you could do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table t1
WHERE UserID||' '||Tag NOT IN (SELECT UserID||' '||Tag FROM table t2
                     WHERE t2.tag = t1.tag
                     ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1000);
```

Putting the spaces in because I know I've had to do similar on Oracle, not sure how MySQL would handle it without.

Comment: hi thanks for reply. I get this error: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery"... My MySQL version is: 5.0.77

Comment: your answer doesn't work in MySQL but I've adapted it in SQL Server. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this with a subquery although I'm not completely sure if MySQL supports that within delete queries. I do know that it can give problems with update queries (I've had some segfaults in MySQL because of this)

Either way... this should work (atleast, it would in Postgres)

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1000)
```

Assuming that `id` is your primary key ofcourse.

**Solution using a temporary table:**

Do note that you'll have to repeat this process for every tag. I can't think of a way to do it in 1 query in MySQL 5.0

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE top_users
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Tag = ...
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY Score DESC
LIMIT 1000;

DELETE FROM table WHERE Tag = ...;

INSERT INTO table
SELECT * FROM top_users;
```

Comment: You also forgot to "GROUP BY Tag"

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery. My MySQL version is: 5.0.77

Comment: @Karl: I assumed that the table was already unique per user. If not than you're completely right ofcourse :)

@Patrick: in that case my query won't work at all. The only clean alternative I see is using a temporary table for the heavy work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a temporary table, who is filled with a select clause

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

I dont have the syntax handy for creating the temporary table, but that will atleast get your the rows you want.

Be careful with delete commands... Better to create a new view/table.

Comment: i think he wants something different. For each tag keep the 1000 highest scoring users. Your select will only get the highest 1000 scoring users overall.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't see "for each tag".  Better add a "GROUP BY Tag" up in there.

Comment: so the resulting query would be ?